# Center of $SU(3)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra, group-representations

I assumed a 3x3 matrix of the form  $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
k & l & m
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then, since we know that the center is always an Abelian invariant subgroup and AB=BA, and the Gell-Mann matrices belong in SU(3), i took $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ which made the first matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & m
\end{pmatrix}$$
Know that $$det(A) =1$$ led to $$a^2m=1$$ And that's my question. Shouldn't i get numbers and not a and m for the center of the group?

Answer (score 1):

The Gell-Mann matrices do not belong to the group ${\rm SU}(3)$. They are a vector-space basis for  ${\rm Lie}\{{\rm SU}(3)\}$, the Lie algebra associated with the group.  The centre $Z\subset {\rm SU}(3)$ is the set of  unit-determinant unitary matrices that commute with all elements of ${\rm SU}(3)$. Schur's lemma tells us that they   have to be multiples of the identity matrix ${\mathbb I}$. So the question for you: If $z\,{\mathbb I} \in {\rm SU}(3)$ what can we say about possible values of $z$?